# Can't see the address when nginx processes the port and outputs 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: django, nginx

I encountered a problem when learning nginx. I have 2 servers on 2 different ports. I want a page with information stored on port 8000 to be returned when accessing "http://localhost/api/v1/clients/". Now I get error 502 Bad Gateway. В консоли: `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 111.11.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/v1/clients/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://111.11.0.2:80/api/v1/clients/", host: "localhost"` If I go to the address: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/clients/", everything is fine. What's my mistake?

nginx:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /api/v1/clients/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend_client/api/v1/clients/; 
    }
}
```

docker:

```
services:
  backend_client:
    build: ./Client
    volumes:
      - ./Client/:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
    command:
      "gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 django_app.wsgi"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17
    container_name: ngx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - backend_client
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your NGINX Configuration. Make sure you are reading some basic information about

- NGINX config [upstreams](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream)
- NGINX config [reverse proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)

Your backend will be available as `backend_client` in your nginx container. The upstream is `backend`. Your app is still listing on port `8000` and this information is important. So tell NGINX about it :).

```sh
upstream backend {
    server backend_client:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /api/v1/clients/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend/; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you! That's exactly what I need)

Comment: That's not how it works though(
I added location to handle server 2 (different port). Now they take turns processing the request(

Comment: upstream backend {
    server backend_client:8000;
    server backend_user:3000;
}
How do I explicitly specify which server to handle?)

Comment: If you want to proxy different request to different servers hosting different applications you have to define another upstream.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again. Good luck to you!

Comment: And if you are still here, could you please answer the last question? I have 2 locations "/api/v1/clients/" and "/api/v1/users/", each tracking a different upstream. And I want to make a location that tracks "static files" by specifying try_files in it. How can I make a condition to load static files from different upstreams depending on location (/api/v1/clients/ or /api/v1/users/) :)

Comment: A good place for you would be our NGINX Community Slack channel. Feel free to to join and ask all your questions there. nginxcommunity.slack.com. I will be around as well.

Comment: Can you send the invite pls? Mail: shievtsovm14@gmail.com